# Anyone know why the Mac OS FTP client was designed read-only?

Tags: ftp, mac-osx, mac

I always found it odd that Mac OS X's `Connect to server` menu lets you read and ***write*** to every protocol it supports *except* FTP. Is it just one of those mysteries, or have they ever discussed why this design choice was made?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple rarely discusses these kinds of decisions, so don't hold your breath for any "official" answer.  Many requests for this feature have flowed into [Apple's bug tracking system](http://bugreport.apple.com) over the years, but so far it seems that the demand is not high enough for Apple to dedicate any resources to implementing it.

In the meantime, there are many excellent full-featured FTP applications for the Mac:

- [Interarchy](http://www.nolobe.com/interarchy/)
- [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/)
- [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/)

And don't forget the `ftp` command-line client that comes with Mac OS X, or the more capable [`ncftp`](http://www.ncftp.com/) command-line client that builds and installs just fine on Mac OS X.

Comment: +1 for Ars ;-) and it's a good answer, but that's beside the point

Comment: Transmit is awesome. +1

Answer (score 3):

@siracusa is right, we'll never know the reason.

If you want the file system style access that the Finder offers, but with write support, there is the [MacFUSE project](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/).  There are two GUI programs for managing these connections [MacFusion](http://www.macfusionapp.org/about.html) (donationware) and [ExpandDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac) (commercial w/trial).